# Parse.com boolean statements

Tags: android, parse-platform

All;

I am making an android application that I need to adjust an image if in the backend a variable is true or false. When the user adds a new ParseObject, I automatically set the wasBillPaid to false.

This creates a Boolean column in my Parse.com backend.

Here is some code.

When the adapter is loaded, I want to check if the Boolean is T or F.

```
        if (ParseConstants.KEY_CREDITOR_BILL_PAID.equals(true)){
            holder.billPaid.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.billNotPaid.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.billPaid.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.billNotPaid.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

Now, I already now the error here. The ParseConstrants.KEY_CREDITOR_BILL_PAID holds the value as a string. This is from the ParseConstrants class.

```
 public static final String KEY_CREDITOR_BILL_PAID = "wasBillPaid";
```

I have two icons overlapping. When the activity loads, I want to check to see what the wasBillPaid variable if its true or false. When you tap the ImageView you control the outcome of what is loading in Parse.com

The below code as onClickListeners and they adjust the ParseConstrant to either true or false depending on what icon is pressed. What am I missing here? When I tap the button, it is not updating the backend in Parse.com

```
 // What happens when we click on the BILL PAID icon
    holder.billPaid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Bills");
            query.getInBackground(ParseConstants.KEY_OBJECTID, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseObject parseObject, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                    if(e == null){
                        parseObject.put(ParseConstants.KEY_CREDITOR_BILL_PAID, true);
                        parseObject.saveInBackground();
                    } else {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            holder.billNotPaid.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.billPaid.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    // What happens when we click on the BILL NOT PAID icon
    holder.billNotPaid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Bills");
            query.getInBackground(ParseConstants.KEY_OBJECTID, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseObject parseObject, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                    if(e == null){
                        parseObject.put(ParseConstants.KEY_CREDITOR_BILL_PAID, false);
                        parseObject.saveInBackground();
                    } else {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            holder.billPaid.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.billNotPaid.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Also, this is in the error log when I click on the button.

```
01-05 23:03:17.931   9266-20636/net.pixeledstudio.bethink I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
01-05 23:03:17.951   9266-20636/net.pixeledstudio.bethink I/System.out﹕ KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
01-05 23:03:18.141    9266-9266/net.pixeledstudio.bethink W/System.err﹕ com.parse.ParseException: no results found for query
01-05 23:03:18.151    9266-9266/net.pixeledstudio.bethink W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.AbstractQueryController$1.then(AbstractQueryController.java:34)
01-05 23:03:18.151    9266-9266/net.pixeledstudio.bethink W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.AbstractQueryController$1.then(AbstractQueryController.java:25)
01-05 23:03:18.151    9266-9266/net.pixeledstudio.bethink W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:798)
01-05 23:03:18.151    9266-9266/net.pixeledstudio.bethink W/System.err﹕ at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
01-05 23:03:18.151    9266-9266/net.pixeledstudio.bethink W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:789)
01-05 23:03:18.151    9266-9266/net.pixeledstudio.bethink W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.access$000(Task.java:32)
01-05 23:03:18.151    9266-9266/net.pixeledstudio.bethink W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$10.then(Task.java:581)
01-05 23:03:18.151    9266-9266/net.pixeledstudio.bethink W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$10.then(Task.java:578)
01-05 23:03:18.151    9266-9266/net.pixeledstudio.bethink W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:875)
01-05 23:03:18.151    9266-9266/net.pixeledstudio.bethink W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.trySetResult(Task.java:913)
01-05 23:03:18.151    9266-9266/net.pixeledstudio.bethink W/System.err﹕ at bolts.TaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(TaskCompletionSource.java:39)
01-05 23:03:18.151    9266-9266/net.pixeledstudio.bethink W/System.err﹕ at bolts.TaskCompletionSource.setResult(TaskCompletionSource.java:62)
01-05 23:03:18.151    9266-9266/net.pixeledstudio.bethink W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$15$1.then(Task.java:856)
01-05 23:03:18.151    9266-9266/net.pixeledstudio.bethink W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$15$1.then(Task.java:843)
01-05 23:03:18.151    9266-9266/net.pixeledstudio.bethink W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:798)
01-05 23:03:18.151    9266-9266/net.pixeledstudio.bethink W/System.err﹕ at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
01-05 23:03:18.151    9266-9266/net.pixeledstudio.bethink W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:789)
01-05 23:03:18.151    9266-9266/net.pixeledstudio.bethink W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.continueWith(Task.java:588)
01-05 23:03:18.151    9266-9266/net.pixeledstudio.bethink W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.continueWith(Task.java:599)
01-05 23:03:18.151    9266-9266/net.pixeledstudio.bethink W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:843)
01-05 23:03:18.151    9266-9266/net.pixeledstudio.bethink W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
01-05 23:03:18.151    9266-9266/net.pixeledstudio.bethink W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
01-05 23:03:18.151    9266-9266/net.pixeledstudio.bethink W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: So I fixed part of it. ParseConstants.KEY_OBJECTID should be as follows ---> mBills.get(position).getObjectId(); mBills being my List<ParseObject> and position being the int position for the getView. Now I just need to fix the if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if (ParseConstants.KEY_CREDITOR_BILL_PAID.equals(true)){
```

error is because of this you are comparing `String` with `boolean`

I think it should be like this

```
public void done(ParseObject parseObject , ParseException e) {
    if(parseObject.getBoolean("<YOUR COLUMN NAME>")){
     holder.billPaid.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.billNotPaid.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        holder.billPaid.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.billNotPaid.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! I knew I was comparing a string to boolean, but my brain stopped working with this statement. Makes sense now, THANK YOU!